# Go through a sprite and save background-position

Tags: javascript, jquery, sprite, background-position

In the game that I have, when the player walks up to the number and presses the "m" key one frame of the sprite is skipped. 
To clarify, the following is my code that I use to keep track of when the frames should change by storing the position of the frames in a variable:

```
function animateStar() {
    var pos = 0;
    $(document).keyup(function(e) {  
        if (e.keyCode == 77) { 
            pos -= 32;
            $('#n1').css('background-position', pos+'px -0px');
          }
    });
}
```

So as you can see, everytime the key code 77 (representing "m") is pressed, the frames will change, since each of my frames has a height and width of 32px.

However, the problem that I am having is that when my player walks away from the object and comes back to it, instead of continuing from where he left off, the frames sort of skip.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/j40s8gjt/

Since my sprite sheet is composed of numbers, you should be able to see what's up with the code.
Try setting the frame at a number between 3-5, walking away from the object then coming back to it and pressing m again, you should see that it sort of re loops everything.

A possible solution of this might be to store the current position of the object when the player leaves it, but I am not sure how to go about doing so.

I hope I've been clear enough, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're defaulting to 0 each time you call `animateStar()` it starts over.

Grabbing the current position is what you need to do instead of defaulting to 0 each time.

in `animateStar()`, Change this line:

```
var pos = 0;
```

to this:

```
var pos = $('#n1').css('background-position').split('px ')[0] || 0;
```

That way it gets the current position when it starts, instead of starting from 0 again and resetting the frame.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/j40s8gjt/2/